# append div on click not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

After appending a `div` onclick is not working. Please help me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".chack").click(function(){
        jQuery( "#pc_form" ).append('<br><div class="apply">apply</div>');
    });

    jQuery(".apply").click(function(){  
        alert();    
    }); 
});
```

```html
<div class="pc_form" id="pc_form">  
    <div class="apply">apply here</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="chack">click</div>
```

Comment: Dynamically inserted element needs delegated event handlers

Comment: how can do plz tell me

Comment: To notify adeneo, use the `@username` syntax: "@adeneo" (note that he should be notified by this comment, so there's no need to spam him beyond this point).

Comment: Those `<div>`s are not keyboard accessible. Replace them with real `<button>`s to fix the issue. http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation.html

Comment: @DavidThomas - And I was notified, thank you! Nikhil, to learn about delegated event handlers, look at the answer below, the duplicate, and do a search, there are thousands of answers on SO that explain this. Also, jQuery has documentation -> **http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pc_form').live("click", ".apply", function() {  alert(); });
```

live event workig

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation to attach events to dynamically added elements:

```
jQuery("body").on('click','.apply',function(){  
   alert('tst');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div.apply` is added with jquery, you have to bind the event to it.Try with -

```
jQuery( "#pc_form" ).append('<br><div class="apply">apply</div>').bind('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('hello');
})
```

Comment: Hello it's working but multiple time call

Comment: It might be because of event propagation.